# How to get `material-dropdown-select` to show current model value

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Using AngularDart + [Angular Components](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components)

I need to create a dropdown that is populated with a small list of items (got this to work), and gets automatically set to the current selection for an object in the model (haven't got this to work).

I have an array of strings in the component called `types`. There is a model object (`selected`) whose field (`type`) corresponds to the list in `types`.

```
<form class="form">
   //other stuff
   <material-dropdown-select>
     <material-select-item *ngFor="let type of types" [selected] = "selected.type == type">
        {{type}}
     </material-select-item>
   </material-dropdown-select>
</form>
```

Despite the `[selected]` attribute, this doesn't sync the current value `selected.type` to the dropdown's default value. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Interestinglt even in this state the dropdown doesn't work as expected - i select a value from the dropdown and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to see how widgets are used is probably going to be the angular_components_examples. For material-dropdown-select you can see the see the examples [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/a982451c2b33e375948dc17eeccd6ff64b11781b/example/material_select_example/lib/material_dropdown_select_demo.html#L157)

In particular for this bracket syntax [] in angular only propagates a value down, not up. So if you want to get an update on a value you would need to use parenthesis (). Or the special syntax [()].

Since this is a form I'd also suggest using the ControlValueAccessor to get the value in the form automatically:

```
<form class="form">
   //other stuff
   <material-dropdown-select [(ngModel)]="selected.type">
     <material-select-item *ngFor="let type of types" [selected] = "selected.type == type">
        {{type}}
     </material-select-item>
   </material-dropdown-select>
</form>
```

you'll also need to add `DropdownSelectValueAccessor` to your directives list.