# How to combine NgForm and [(ngModel)] with MaterialSelectComponent and MaterialDropdownSelectComponent?

Tags: dart, angular-components, angular-dart, angular-forms

I know that this question similar to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630483/is-it-possible-to-use-material-select-with-ngmodel-ngcontrol) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914608/how-to-get-material-dropdown-select-to-show-current-model-value), but let me explain it with detail sample code.

I combine code from angular_components material_select_example [3](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/examples/material_select_example/lib/material_select_demo.dart) and [4](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/examples/material_select_example/lib/material_dropdown_select_full_demo.dart), using component `material-select` and `material-dropdown-select`. (for clarity, I put the full code at the bottom)

I want to process the form result with NgForm,
for example, now I use a method `logConsole(NgForm form)`.

what I have tried with material-select,

```html
<material-select focusList [selection]="targetLanguageSelection"
                 [(ngModel)]="selectionValue" #langVal="ngForm" (ngControl)="langVal"
                 class="bordered-list">
```

the `logConsole()` print empty Map (`Map(0)`). I still can get the value from `targetLanguageSelection.selectedValues`.

from above code, if I set `ngControl="langVal"`, I got an exception:

```
No value accessor for (langVal) or you may be missing formDirectives in your directives list.
```

then I changed to material-dropdown-select, I can't use `ngControl` because the `buttonText` will not show the selected value.

```html
<material-dropdown-select
        [buttonText]="selectionValue == null ? 'Select Language' : selectionValue.uiDisplayName"
        [(ngModel)]="selectionValue" #langVal="ngForm"
        [options]="languageListOptions"  displayNameRenderer>
```

but it still failed, the `logConsole()` still print empty Map (`Map(0)`). I still can get the value from `selectionValue`.

so how to get the value with NgForm?

**EDIT**:
I still looking at how I can get `NgForm` value from `MaterialSelectComponent`, 
I already can get `NgForm` value with `MaterialDropdownSelectComponent` with `ngControl` not `(ngControl)`, like below:

```html
<material-dropdown-select
        [buttonText]="selectionValue == null ? 'Select Language' : selectionValue.uiDisplayName"
        [(ngModel)]="selectionValue" #langVal="ngForm" ngControl="langVal"
        [options]="languageListOptions"  displayNameRenderer>
</material-dropdown-select>
```

--

here is the *material_select_demo_component.dart*.

```dart
@Component(
  selector: 'material-select-demo',
  providers: popupBindings,
  directives: [
    materialInputDirectives,
    formDirectives,
    displayNameRendererDirective,
    FocusListDirective,
    FocusItemDirective,
    MaterialSelectComponent,
    MaterialSelectItemComponent,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialDropdownSelectComponent,
    DropdownSelectValueAccessor,
    NgFor,
  ],
  templateUrl: 'material_select_demo_component.html',
  styleUrls: ['material_select_demo_component.css'],
)
class MaterialSelectDemoComponent {
  final SelectionModel<Language> targetLanguageSelection =
      SelectionModel.single();

  Language selectionValue;

  ExampleSelectionOptions languageListOptions =
      ExampleSelectionOptions(_languagesList);

  List<Language> get languagesList => _languagesList;

  void logConsole(NgForm form) {
    html.window.console.log(form.value);
    html.window.console.log(selectionValue);
    html.window.console
        .log(targetLanguageSelection.selectedValues.toList().toString());
  }

  static const List<Language> _languagesList = <Language>[
    Language('en-US', 'US English'),
    Language('en-UK', 'UK English'),
    Language('fr-CA', 'Canadian English'),
    Language('zh-CN', 'Chichewa'),
    Language('zh-TW', 'Chinese'),
    Language('ny', 'Chinese (Simplified)'),
    Language('zh', 'Chinese (Traditional)'),
  ];
}

class Language implements HasUIDisplayName {
  final String code;
  final String label;
  const Language(this.code, this.label);
  String toString() => '${label} (${code})';
  @override
  String get uiDisplayName => label;
}

class ExampleSelectionOptions extends StringSelectionOptions<Language>
    implements Selectable<Language> {
  ExampleSelectionOptions(List<Language> options)
      : super(options,
            toFilterableString: (Language option) => option.toString());
  ExampleSelectionOptions.withOptionGroups(List<OptionGroup> optionGroups)
      : super.withOptionGroups(optionGroups,
            toFilterableString: (Language option) => option.toString());
  @override
  SelectableOption getSelectable(Language item) =>
      item is Language && item.code.contains('en')
          ? SelectableOption.Disabled
          : SelectableOption.Selectable;
}
```

here's the *material_select_demo_component.html*:

```html
<form #languageForm="ngForm">
<section>
    <material-select focusList [selection]="targetLanguageSelection" class="bordered-list">
        <material-select-item *ngFor="let language of languagesList"
                              focusItem [value]="language"
                              displayNameRenderer>
        </material-select-item>
    </material-select>
</section>
<section>
    <material-dropdown-select
            [buttonText]="selectionValue == null ? 'Select Language' : selectionValue.uiDisplayName"
            [options]="languageListOptions" [(ngModel)]="selectionValue" displayNameRenderer>
    </material-dropdown-select>
</section>
    <material-button raised (click)="logConsole(languageForm)">submit</material-button>
</form>
```

the *pubspec.yaml* file

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.4.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^6.0.0-alpha
  angular_components: ^0.14.0-alpha
  angular_forms: ^2.1.3
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start with something very simple and using FormBuilder:

```dart
class Language {
  final String code;
  final String label;
  const Language(this.code, this.label);

  @override
  String toString() => label;
}
```

In your component :

```dart
StringSelectionOptions<Language> languageOptions = StringSelectionOptions<Language>(_languagesList);
Language selectedLanguage;

ControlGroup myForm;

void ngOnInit() {
    myForm = FormBuilder.controlGroup({
      'language': FormBuilder.controlGroup([selectedLanguage]);
    });
}

void onSubmit() {
   print(myForm.value);
   print(selectedLanguage);
}
```

```html
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <material-dropdown-select
            buttonText="{{selectedLanguage??'Choose ...'}}"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"
            ngControl="language"
            [options]="languageOptions">
    </material-dropdown-select>
    <material-button
            [disabled]="!myForm.valid"
            (trigger)="onSubmit()">Submit</material-button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, will try it first. actually, I'm looking more information about FormBuilder since someone mentions about reactive form in the angular dart, but I still can't get complete example or article about it. that's why I use code from angular dart material component. do you have a good reference for FormBuilder (and maybe reactive form)?

Comment: here's the previous SO that I read, you answered there too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971760/angulardart-creating-a-form-with-reactive-form-builder

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a concrete example. I've learned by myself, by looking into doc and angular_components examples.